# Как удалить элементы из XML-файла через PHP?

Tags: php, xml, delete

Как удалить элементы из XML-файла через PHP?

вот сам файл

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<html/>
<url>
<loc>http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=41</loc>
<lastmod>2019-10-29T21:07:05+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=42</loc>
<lastmod>2019-10-29T21:08:00+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=43</loc>
<lastmod>2019-10-29T22:00:06+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=44</loc>
<lastmod>2019-10-30T00:39:54+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=45&name=gug_mkrtchyan_-_mam_jan_2019
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-10-30T09:16:32+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Требуется удалить эту запись:

```
<url>
<loc>http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=41</loc>
<lastmod>2019-10-29T21:07:05+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$file2 = file('klose.xml', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );

$rep='<url><loc>http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=41</loc><lastmod>2019-10-29T21:07:05+03:00</lastmod><changefreq>weekly</changefreq></url>';

$data=str_replace($rep, '', $file2);

file_put_contents('nol.xml', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('0.xml');

$documentElement = $document->documentElement;

$urls = $documentElement->getElementsByTagName('url');

$nodeToRemove = null;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $attrValue = $url->getAttribute('loc');
    if ($url->getElementsByTagName('loc')->item(0)->nodeValue === 'http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=41') {
        $nodeToRemove = $url;
    }
}

if ($nodeToRemove !== null) {
    $documentElement->removeChild($nodeToRemove);
}

file_put_contents('0.xml', $document->saveXML());
```